# Yii2 - Attributes in DynamicModel

Tags: model-view-controller, model, yii2

I created a `yii\base\DynamicModel` in controller and I have one form with attributes from this model. I need access these attributes after submitting form in controller.

**controller.php**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new DynamicModel([
        'name', 'age', 'city'
    ]);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $model->age = $model->age + 5;
        /*
         * code....
         * */
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But `$model->age`, `$model->name` etc. returns nothing.

I could only access the attribute this way: `Yii::$app->request->get('DynamicModel')['age']`

What is the correct way to access these attributes?

Comment: How does your view look? And model must use at least one validation rule for the attribute to be loaded.

Comment: @Bizley you are absolutely right! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure validation rules in order to automatically load attributes by `load()`:

```
$model = new DynamicModel(['name', 'age', 'city']);
$model->addRule(['name', 'age', 'city'], 'safe');

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
// ...
```

Using `safe` will accept values as is without actual validation, but you may consider adding [real validation rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation) to ensure correct state of your model.

Comment: you are absolutely right! tanks! one more litle question, its possible define the name of `DynamicModel`, for example when i use search in `DynamicModel` now the url is  `controller/index?DynamicModel[name]=John` and i need something similar of this `controller/index?PeopleSearch[name]=John` ?